# An alternative to strong naming in .Net framework

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, disassembly, strongname

**TL;DR:** What is the alternative for strong-naming my assembly to be a trusted/authenticated dev (by utilizing the .Net framework)?

---

"Long" story:

So I've been trying to sign my assembly and thus program I've written with VB.Net for quite a long time now.
The problem is, that I would theoretically strong-name my assembly so that I am "easily" accepted as a trusted developer in any Windows version that supports the features.

But now I use a third-party assembly for some functionalities which is **not** strong-named.
As I've found out by now, is, that I can't reference non-strong-named assemblies by a strong-named assembly.
Which means, that I either have to ditch the functionalities provided by the third-party assembly or stop strong-naming my own assembly.
Also, sometimes Windows kills my program direclty after launching it, because the strong-name is not from a verified source, yet (only the "test.snk" provided by Visual Studio).

(And yes, I tried [strong-naming the *.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error) but I wasn't able because of some errors which I dont understand yet)
([Also related](https://dzone.com/articles/net-fu-zero-delay-signing-of-a))

**So now my question is:**

What are the alternatives to show users/the os that you're trustworthy and the original author of the program?

Comment: Strong naming isn't authenticode, and it's the latter that's usually involved in e.g. displaying "this software comes from an untrusted source"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27210148/613130 on this argument. Didn't know. Thought the signature was still checked. Really thought the signature was checked. So you can "append" any signature to a dll?